# lines() command now creating weird connected plot?

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to replot data with the same code which looked fine the first time but now the lines are all oddly connected. Here's the code:

```
lines(x, predict(gam.ns), col=1, lwd=2)
```

And examples of what I'm getting now [image]

And what I was getting before (with additional data plotted) and would like to have again
[image]

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: It's easier to help if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset, all of the relevant code and any errors or warnings - all in a plain text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lines()` connects points in order.  Your data set was previously sorted in order of `x`, this version isn't.  You can either go back upstream and order them, or:

```r
ox <- order(x)
lines(x[ox], predict(gam.ns)[ox], col=1, lwd=2)
```

`x[ox]` is identical to `sort(x)`, but you need `ox` because you want to arrange the predicted values in the same order ...

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate but it would take longer to find the correct target (I did spend a minute searching) than to write the answer ...